# Android 5.0 emulator showing Storage space running out

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop

I just updated Android SDK to version 21 and trying to start emulator. I am using Nexus 4 with CPU Intel atom (x86) 768 RAM and 524 internal storage. Emulator starts fine but it shows en error message, "Storage space running out" and it is very slow. I tried increasing the RAM also but didn't work. What could be the issue?

Comment: "524 internal storage" -- that's your problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying. What is the solution ?

Comment: @323go Up your storage space from 524mb cause that is super low anyway... do I win?

Comment: @323go Its rude of you. I have already tried increasing RAM and internal membory both, It does not solve my issue. Thats why I thought you were talking about something else and was asking about the solution.

Comment: I have found the resolution. Peace :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
emulator -avd "Name" -partition-size 500
```

This solved the issue for me.

Update on how to execute above command:

1. Go to a terminal
2. `cd [android SDK directory]/tools/`
3. linux terminal: `./emulator -avd nameOfAvd -partition-size 500 &`
   windows : `emulator -avd nameOfAvd -partition-size 500`

Comment: Does not work for me. I tried -partition-size 1024, because it is already 512 MB and only got < 100 MB left after boot... to small for my App to install.

Comment: Did not work for me, also tried recreating avd... did not work.

Comment: BUT this problem seems to no more occur in API level 23, will be my bug turn-around.

Comment: I have created device with 10G storage, 2G sdcard, still "running out of storage". even wiped data multiple times. But it shows only after i try to hot restart the app,

Answer (score 38):

Open AVD Manager --> Wipe Data

[image]

Comment: Thanks 
Simple solution

Comment: This doesn't suffice if the internal storage after OS installation is too small. If this is the case, you need to increase internal storage as described in the answers by @FISH79.

Answer (score 31):

You have to go in your android folder e.g. on OSX ~/.android/avd/{YOUR_AVD_NAME} and edit file config.ini.

Just add or modify row `disk.dataPartition.size = YOUR_SIZE`

e.g. `disk.dataPartition.size = 1G`

Then you may have to wipe your emulator's disk.

Answer (score 10):

Go to AVD manager on your android studio. 
click on the pencil icon of the virtual device.
on the pop up window click on advanced settings at the bottom.
scroll down to memory and storage and alter the default definitions of MB/GB etc.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now. Why didn't I see before that you can scroll in that advanced settings window?

Answer (score 0):

REinstal the emulator..
Go to your AVD location and delete all the files in avd folder( C:\Users\acer.android\avd ), 
then Go to android studio AVD Manager and install a new emulator. 
( but this will erase the current emulator so, you'll need to download it again..)