# Android emulator sometimes showing "Storage space running out", makes adb hang on APK install

Tags: android, android-emulator

Every once in a while, while developing on Android and testing on the emulator, I notice that in the emulator the notification "Storage space running out". Usually this is accompanied by `adb` not being able to install my app's APK anymore: no errors, installation simply never ends.

What is causing this space issue? How to solve it?

There are workarounds. Sometimes restarting the emulator solves the problem, but it reoccurs shortly after. Also wiping the data solves the issue, but again, it reappears after some time (much later than restarting). Both solutions are sub-optimal because they interrupt the development flow, especially wiping the data.

This problem is not related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593711/android-5-0-emulator-showing-storage-space-running-out), where the space issue comes after updating the emulator to Lollipop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the problem is related to LeakCanary that is installed in my app. Reports are never cleaned, and being fairly large, they quickly consume the storage. Cleaning the reports directory solves the issue without wiping the data:

```
rm -r /data/media/0/Download/leakcanary-*
```

This doesn't solve the issue permanently. Either fix the leaks reported by LeakCanary or, if there's no solution for them, instruct it to not report certain leaks.